# What does "'Go to Parent/Child Commit' is not allowed" in Intellij IDEA pair programming mean?

Tags: intellij-idea, pair-programming

While doing pair programming in Intellij IDEA, there seems to be places in the code where when I place my cursor, I can't move my cursor with left/right arrow key.

When I press left arrow then I get this notification:
[image: 'Go to Parent Commit' is not allowed.]

When I press right arrow then I get a similar notification, only with "Child Commit" instead of "Parent Commit".

It is also worth mentioning that I already have write access. It is puzzling because I still can write and delete code in these places. I just can't move my cursor with arrow keys. I can however move my cursor with arrow keys just fine in some other places.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with permissions. Can you try with Full Access permissions?

If the issues is ongoing please report it as a bug.